# Get user details after OneDrive authentication

Tags: ios, swift, onedrive

I'm trying to authenticate user using OneDrive API. User authentication is successfully done. But, I also want to get the user email or name once user is authenticated. Below is my current code

```
ODClient.setMicrosoftAccountAppId(ODAppKey, scopes: ["wl.signin", "wl.offline_access", "onedrive.readonly", "onedrive.readwrite", "onedrive.appfolder"])

ODClient.clientWithCompletion({ (client, error) -> Void in
    if(error == nil){
        odClient = client
    }
})
```

How can I get the login user detail once user is authenticated. Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as:

```
ODClient.clientWithCompletion({ (client, error) -> Void in
    if(error == nil){
        odClient = client
        self.getUserDetails()
    }
})

func getUserDetails(){
    odClient.drive().request().getWithCompletion { (drive, error) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
            print("User name : \(drive.owner.user.displayName)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note : With OneDrive we can only get the display name if it is set for an account.

Thanks to @ginach

Answer (score 0):

When you [retrieve a drive](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/drives/get.md) it returns an owner object that includes display name but email is not currently supported in the OneDrive API. [This issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/202) tracks adding that support.

Comment: So, should I have to make GET drive  request call after authentication is completed? or is there any other way.

Comment: Yes, if you do a get on /drive after authenticating the user it will give you the name and eventually (hopefully) the email.